# How to delete older rows with no change since previous row by ID using Power Query Editor

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a single table with three columns: `ID`, `Score`, and `Date`.

```
     Current Data
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          ID         |       Score      |       Date       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          123        |         3        |       05/01      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          123        |         2        |       04/25      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          123        |         2        |       04/20      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          123        |         1        |       04/15      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          123        |         2        |       04/10      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          123        |         1        |       04/05      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          456        |         6        |       04/30      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          456        |         5        |       04/20      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          456        |         4        |       04/10      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          456        |         4        |       04/05      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          456        |         6        |       04/01      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

```
     Desired Table
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          ID         |       Score      |       Date       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          123        |         3        |       05/01      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          123        |         2        |       04/25      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          123        |         1        |       04/15      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          123        |         2        |       04/10      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          123        |         1        |       04/05      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          456        |         6        |       04/30      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          456        |         5        |       04/20      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          456        |         4        |       04/10      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          456        |         6        |       04/01      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

I'm trying to only show rows where the value has changed for the ID. I think using 'Remove Duplicates' goes too far and excludes when the value goes from `1` to `2` to `1` to `2` (I want to show all four rows/values but it only shows the latest `1` and `2`).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it sounds like you are trying to do is tag all the rows in a sorted list where [ID=previous row ID] AND [Score=previous row Score]

Add an index, then refer to the value of **ColumnName** in the previous row using

```
= #"PreviousStepName"{[Index]-1}[ColumnName]
```

Code that uses this to create if/then formula to tag the ones to remove, and then remove them

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}}),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type" ,{{"ID", Order.Ascending}, {"Date", Order.Descending}}),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Sorted Rows" , "Index", 0, 1),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index" , "Custom", each if [Index]=0 then null else if [ID] = #"Sorted Rows"{[Index]-1}[ID] and [Score] = #"Sorted Rows"{[Index]-1}[Score] then "remove" else null),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([Custom] = null)),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Index", "Custom"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```

edited to swap the sort and index rows per comment

Comment: It worked for me but I needed to swap indexing and sorting